# How to calculate RSA private key in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I am creating a program that encrypts and decrypt data. I need to calculate the secret key but I can't work out how to change the algebra into a expression that can be used in python.

I tried using algebra but I could not figure it out.
I'm using python 3.6.1

```python
def genkey():
    p = 3 #prime 1
    q = 11 #prime 2
    n = p * q# pubkey part 1
    z = (p-1)*(q-1)# 20
    k = 7 #coprime to z and pub key part 2
    #j = ?
    return (n,k,j)
```

j should equal 3 and formula is
*k * j = 1 ( mod z )*

> I am using pre-calculated numbers for testing

[Link to site](http://sergematovic.tripod.com/rsa1.html)

Comment: You need to read up on the extended Euclidean algorithm. It should be covered in any sufficiently complete discussion of RSA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For RSA:

I will provide some algorithms and codes from my own Bachelor Thesis

- p and q, two prime numbers
- n = p*q, `n` is the part of the public key
- `e` or `public exponent` should be coprime with Euler function for `n` which is `(p-1)(q-1)` for prime numbers

Code for finding public exponent:

```
def find_public_key_exponent(euler_function):
    """
    find_public_key_exponent(euler_function)

    Finds public key exponent needed for encrypting.
    Needs specific number in order to work properly.

    :param euler_function: the result of euler function for two primes.
    :return:               public key exponent, the element of public key.
    """

    e = 3

    while e <= 65537:
        a = euler_function
        b = e

        while b:
            a, b = b, a % b

        if a == 1:
            return e
        else:
            e += 2

    raise Exception("Cant find e!")
```

- next we need modular multiplicative inverse of Euler function(n) and e, which equals `d`, our last component:

```
def extended_euclidean_algorithm(a, b):
    """
    extended_euclidean_algorithm(a, b)

    The result is the largest common divisor for a and b.

    :param a: integer number
    :param b: integer number
    :return:  the largest common divisor for a and b
    """

    if a == 0:
        return b, 0, 1
    else:
        g, y, x = extended_euclidean_algorithm(b % a, a)
        return g, x - (b // a) * y, y


def modular_inverse(e, t):
    """
    modular_inverse(e, t)

    Counts modular multiplicative inverse for e and t.

    :param e: in this case e is a public key exponent
    :param t: and t is an Euler function
    :return:  the result of modular multiplicative inverse for e and t
    """

    g, x, y = extended_euclidean_algorithm(e, t)

    if g != 1:
        raise Exception('Modular inverse does not exist')
    else:
        return x % t
```

*Public key:* `(n, e)`
*Private key:* `(n, d)`

*Encryption:* `<number> * e mod n = <cryptogram>`

*Decryption:* `<cryptogram> * d mon n = <number>`

There are some more restrictions so the cipher should be secure but it will work with conditions I provided.

And of course you need to find your way to get large prime numbers, read about [prime testing](https://brilliant.org/wiki/prime-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate phi using p and q:

```
phi = (p-1) * (q-1)
```

Use built in python function pow passing in public exponent and phi:

```
pow(e, -1, phi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution by Matthew above but using the python module egcd (Extended Euclidean Algorithm)

```
pip3 install egcd
```

Then in python window

```
from egcd import egcd
phi = (p-1) * (q-1)
d = egcd(e, phi)[1] % phi
```